# Magento 2 Reset order increment id after deleting test orders

Tags: orders, increment-id

I've cleaned my db from the test orders, following this instructions here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861046/how-to-remove-test-orders-from-magento2

But the order increment id, still remains the same.

Which table do I to `alter` to reset the `order increment id`?
I see the sequence is incremented in `sequence_order_1` table but I'm not sure if this would be the correct place

Answer (score 3):

You can rollback order `increment_last_id`, stored in `eav_entity_store` associated with `order` entity type.